# Why apt is not finding already installed package?

Tags: apt, package-management, search

On Ubuntu 22.04.3:

```
paul@box4x4:~$ apt search libstdc++ | grep installed

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libstdc++-11-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libstdc++-12-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed]
libstdc++6/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

which shows that `libstdc++-12-dev` is already installed. Searching for it with:

```
paul@box4x4:~$ apt search libstdc++-12-dev
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

fails. Why is that?

Comment: @ThomasWard I tried both quotes `"` and `'` with negative result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `apt search libstdc\\+\\+-12-dev` instead.

`man apt` says:

> ```
>   search (apt-cache(8))
>       search can be used to search for the given regex(7) term(s)
> ```

No, this is not a problem with `bash` expansion. If it was doing expansion, `echo` will help you debug what it is expanding to:

```
home@daniel-tablet1:~$ echo apt search libstdc++-12-dev
apt search libstdc++-12-dev
home@daniel-tablet1:~$ echo apt search 'libstdc++-12-dev'
apt search libstdc++-12-dev
```

The problem is that you wrote `libstdc++-12-dev`. This, when interpreted as a RegEx, means:

- The string `libstd` literally
- In effect, any number of c's. Literally, or more matches of the preceding, namely:

  - In effect, any number of c's. Literally, or more matches of the preceding, namely: (Having this nested twice is redundant)

    - The string `c` literally
- The string `-12-dev` literally

`apt search 'libstdc\+\+-12-dev'` works just as well as `apt search libstdc\\+\\+-12-dev`. To escape the backslashes from `bash`, you either need to quote or double them. Then, the `apt` RegEx engine needs a backslash to tell it to interpret `+` as a literal string instead of "one or more of the preceding."